# How to access items of 'Device' data type in python?

Tags: python, typeerror

Basically I have a variable named `dev_handle`  and the value of it is

```
print(dev_handle)

output:

Device RET789-452.234 (alias=RET789), type poplk
```

I do not know the type of the variable , but I know its not int, or string, or list or dict.

I want to access the value `poplk`
I also want to check if `poplk` exists in the variable `dev_handle`

When I tried the following code

```
 print(dev_handle[type])
```

I get the following error

```
print(dev_handle[type])
ERROR: TypeError: 'Device' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I access the variable elements to access `poplk`

This is where the variable `dev_handle` is created,

```
def get_details(self, testscript, device_ip):
testbed_device_data = {}
            for device, device_detail in testscript.parameters['testbed'].devices.items():
                if device_detail.alias not in ['qwerPA', 'qwerLA', 'TESTManager']:
                    if device_ip == str(device_detail.connections.cli.ip):
                        device_type = device_detail.os
                        testbed_device_data.update({str(device_detail.connections.cli.ip): device_detail})
                        logger.info(testbed_device_data)
                        dev_handle = testbed_device_data[device_ip]
                        logger.info(dev_handle)
                        logger.info(device_type)
                        break
            return testbed_device_data, dev_handle, device_type
```

The above method will read a testbed.yaml file which has details of the device in jason format and picks it and stores it in `dev_handle` and then returns it

Comment: You should be able to use `type(dev_handle)` to get the type/class of the variable.

Comment: @TYZ I tried that , but it did not print anything.

Comment: did you do `print(type(dev_handle))`? Secondly, maybe this works: `dev_handle.type`?

Comment: Where is this variable from in your code/script? If you show more context about the work you are doing, maybe we can have better clues.

Comment: @TYZ I added the method where `dev_handle` is created

Comment: show some data from device json file and show dict testbed_device_data so we can have some clues